# How to implement place picker in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm trying to make a simple app which shows the information of the selected place on the Google map. From android documentation, I found that it can be done by using `Place Picker`. I am following [this](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker) tutorial provided by Google.

In this docs it is said that I've to use following code for launch the `place picker`.

```
int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

and also given the following method to retrieve the details of the place selected by the user.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
        String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
        Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
}
```

But My problem is Where should I place this code in my app? In my `MapsActivity` or in the other class file?

I've following code, which displays the map.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));


}
}
```

What changes should I make in above class to invoke the `place picker`. And if the 1st code snippet should be placed in above class, than how it can be implemented? I tried many times to find this type of example, but can't find one which can solve my problem.Particularly I've tried [this](http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/using-new-google-places-api-android/) tutorial. But it give lots of errors.

I'm beginner in android. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial in second link (truiton.com) works fine for Me. You need to put this code

```
int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

in a block which executes on a particular action like in the tutorial and the function inside the class. You can it in the MapsActivity class itself if it has some user action option.